# I want to add a point when the if statement returns true

Tags: javascript

How can I add a point every time `resu.html()` is equal to `"its a tie"`. I tried to write an if statement but it doesn't seem to work.

```
            if(pl1.val() == result){
                resu.html('its a tie');
                resu.css({'left':'45.3%'});
            }
            //
            if(pl1.val() == 1 && result == 2){
            resu.html('Player 1 Wins the game');
            resu.css({'left':'37%'});
            } // That's how we have to get "its a tie" don't mind it

    var resu = $('.result');
            function pointCounter(){
                var point = 1;
                if(resu.html() == "its a tie"){
                    $('.point').html(point++);
                }
            }
    $('button').click(pointCounter);
```

```
<p>You currently have <span class="point">1</span> Point</p>
<p class="result"></p>
<button>START</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you need to define point var outside the function.

```
<script>
    var i = 0;
    function buttonClick() {
        document.getElementById('inc').value = ++i;
    }
</script>

<button onclick="buttonClick()">Click Me</button>
<input type="text" id="inc" value="0"></input>
```